# $3 \times 8$ Array Problem: Finding the Longest Line Containing Exactly 3 Dots

Tags: radicals

In the $3 \times 8$ array, the dots are evenly spaced horizontally and vertically with each dot 1 cm from the nearest neighboring dots. In simplest radical form, what is the number of units in the length of the longest segment containing exactly 3 dots, two of which are the segment's endpoints?

Comment: Any thoughts?  What's the longest segment you've produced so far?

Comment: I found the segment sqrt(10)+ sqrt(17), but then I found that it was wrong. I found this by just drawing a line from the top left corner to the middle dot, and then another segment to the bottom right corner.

Comment: Well, I expect they mean a straight line segment.  Draw the picture and try to make long line segments.  There really aren't a lot of options.

Comment: How are you sure if a segment is straight if it passes through 3 points?

Comment: Draw the grid on the usual $(x,y)-$ plane.  Corners at $(0,0),(2,0),(2,7), (0,7)$.  Now you know what straight lines are (constant slope).  For instance the segment connecting $(0,0), (1,1), (2,2)$ is a straight line (part of $y=x$).  Probably not maximal though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does the below figure help at all?

[image]

Comment: Oh! Ok, thank you so much! I guess since there is no "middle" point for the 3*8 rectangle, the only way to find the longest segment is using a 3*7 rectangle.

Comment: So may an upvote, or accept ($\checkmark$) is in order?